# how do I get 11.10 to replace the Juniper driver with Catalyst

Tags: video, graphics

I downloaded Catalyst and installed but settings still shows Juniper.  Although I have a Radeon 5770, I think I'm still in 2D mode.  Can't load the extensions to catalyst and can't run flash.

Answer (score 1):

See post #4 in this thread. It worked perfectly for me, and I have a 6770 card, which is the same as a 5770.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1873072

Tim

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.